# How do I save the state of my web page, when the page is saved on my PC and not online?

Tags: javascript, html

My web pages are saved on my PC, not online. I have .html files and .txt files to edit them. localStorage and sessionStorage won't work. I have yet to try cookies but I'm assuming they wont work either. I need to know either how to save the state of my pages to a specified path, or I need to know how to put my pages on a server so localStorage will work properly.

I'm attempting to program a video game. I'm familiar with most aspects of video games, saving should be simpler than this. I am only familiar with html and JavaScript. Here is an example of some code that is supposed to make localStorage work, (it works fine as long as the page with the code is online).

I've tried both localStorage and sessionStorage, but my pages are not online, they are saved on my PC.

```
    <body>

<div id="result"></div>

<script>
// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  // Store
  sessionStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
  // Store
  sessionStorage.setItem("firstname","John ");
  // Retrieve

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
  sessionStorage.getItem("firstname")+
  sessionStorage.getItem("lastname");

} else {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does 
not support Web Storage...";
}
</script>

</body>
```

This result of the code is supposed to read "John Smith" (without quotes). Actual result, nothing. Like I said, my pages are stored on my PC, I don't know how to load pages onto the web, I'm a bit of a noob there. I know the code works because I got that code from w3schools and it worked fine there. Is there a way to save the state of my page, WITHOUT uploading pages? If not, how do I upload my pages to a server?

Comment: I would recommend looking at something like xampp as a local web server. That way you don't have to upload your code to a "server", but instead the server runs just on run computer.

Comment: I'll try that and let you know how it works for me

Comment: Will xampp also accept html and javascript? I watched a setup video on youtube and the only programming languages listed were PHP and PERL.

Comment: PHP is the backend. It will help to handle the data you send to your server from your html pages. You can even use the javascript's [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) api.

Comment: I wonder if the issue here is that the HTML document is being loaded via `file:` and not `http:`. Local storage should work fine if you have a local web server and you are connecting via HTTP.

Comment: I do not understand how to use the software xampp let alone trying to learn PHP for this. When I downloaded the xampp, it opened, it didn't leave a shortcut, and once I exited out of it, I couldn't figure out how to get back to it. I searched for it on my pc and all I found was the original xampp installer.exe I don't want to reinstall it.

Comment: @halfer , how do I go about connecting via HTTP?

Comment: Serve the page from a web server, and make sure you are using `http://localhost` in your web browser. Was I correct in assuming you are using `file://` currently?

Comment: @halfer , It was a problem with the browser I was using, my code works (almost) perfect on Google Chrome. Now I'm having problems with my code after I save the state then load it. As long as I don't try to save then load my code works perfect. But for some reason, when I save, then load (all vars appear to load fine) then I execute a piece of code and things go haywire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the following code and save it as `mySite.html` somewhere on your computer.
Then double click the file to open in a browser. Or drag and drop the file to a browser. That should work. Nothing else is needed. To change it, just use a text editor and save it. Refresh your browser to see the changes.

Updated code including a `localStorage` example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>John Thompson Site #1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="error"></div>
  <div id="sessionStorage">sessionStorage</div>
  <div id="localStorage">localStorage</div>

  <script>
  // Check browser support
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Store
    sessionStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
    // Store
    sessionStorage.setItem("firstname","John ");
    // Retrieve and write to HTML
    document.getElementById("sessionStorage").innerHTML =
    sessionStorage.getItem("firstname")+
    sessionStorage.getItem("lastname");

    // added localstorage example here
    // store
    localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
    // Retrieve and write to HTML
    document.getElementById("localStorage").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('myCat');

  } else {
    document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
  }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: awesome, sessionStorage is working, now to get localStorage to work.

Comment: Localstorage works about the same, I've updated the answer including a simple `localStorage` example. @JohnThompson if your question is answered please mark as accepted.

Comment: @cramba - All that's showing up on the page is sessionStorage and localStorage with a line break in between them.

Comment: @cramba- My bad man. I opened my page with Google Chrome instead of Internet Explorer this time and it works like a charm, and I marked this as accepted. The add to your rep wont show up for me because my rep is less than 15.